# Setting rout to static files in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to express, but am trying to follow best practices. I want to serve my files like css or index.html form a folder named 'public'. Some examples that I follow use .use and .get methods that look like this

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

Using first example I get some sort of an error where content can't get loaded, second example works, but I'm not sure that it achieves the exact task I am looking for as it seems to only sevr index.html file. I looked up the documentation, both are present there, however I don't understand when each should be used. Could you please clarify what these methods do and how to set 'public' folder to be used in application in order to keep static files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there ;-).

```
app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

This gets the job done. First provide the url path under which your public directory should be available, then provide the local path to the directory.